# UIRefreshControl without tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I have someone managed to add a `UIRefreshController` (or something similar) to a `View` without a `UITableView`? My `View` is embedded in a `UINavigationController` and I'd like to "pull down to refresh" the view under the `NavigationBar`.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `UIScrollView` would do. AFAIK, objects that can scroll will able to use `UIRefreshControl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it with UIScrollView... Works like a charm...

Comment: Just create a `UIRefreshControl` and add it as a subview to the scroll view.